# Checkbox not showing in angular 12

Tags: angular

I am just trying to do a simple checkbox in angular and it doesn't seem to show up.

I am not doing anything fancy but nothing shows. Just got this off a website. "Terms 2" shows up fine but not the checkbox.

```
<div>
  <input #saveUserNameCheckBox id="saveUserNameCheckBox" 
      type="checkbox" [checked]="saveUsername"
    (change)="onSaveUsernameChanged(saveUserNameCheckBox.checked)" /> Terms 2
</div>
```

Comment: Inspect element to check whether the checkbox beside "Terms 2" is rendered or not. If it is rendered, check its CSS styling rule as possible that the rule may lead to this "issue".

Answer (score 0):

Open up your inspector and select your input. Something must be overwriting it.

I pasted your code here and it shows up just fine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h4pcux?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html